# Convert excel to pdf or create new pdf file?

Tags: java, file, pdf, xls

I am developing a web app using java. I can create reports in excel files for the user to download. Now I am told to give the option of downloading it in a pdf file. Should I use a library to create pdf and write the content or look up a way to convert the excel file into pdf? I think the second option would be easier to develop, but are there any disadvantages on doing this? And if this is the best option, what would be a good library to convert xls to pdf?

Comment: Why don't you use a reporting tool like [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)?  Define your report once, output in various formats (excel, word, pdf, ...)?

Comment: Jasper Reports is a good option, though it does have a rather steep learning curve

Comment: Also, jasper reports is not friendly if you need a dynamic number of columns in any of your tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this question will help you: [How to convert ms-Excel file to pdf in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735697/how-to-convert-ms-excel-file-to-pdf-in-java)

They recommend iText there but you should be aware that [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) exists.  This will let you render html/css as a PDF.  It may be a better level of abstraction to work at.

Comment: Flying Saucer looks cool.  Wish I'd known about that at my previous job... lol.

Comment: Link to the question is broken.

Comment: I used Flying Saucer in Android but give me no class dex found for AffineTransform

Answer (score 2):

You might check out Apache FOP for PDF creation, and POI for reading the excel.  I used both pretty extensively in my previous job.

http://poi.apache.org/

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: can excel files be converted to pdf with FOP?